# Laravel query escaping the period (.)

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm in the process of updating an API which is based on Laravel.

Using the Eloquent DB Model I've written a scope to narrow down my query to that of what we require.

The issue I'm facing is that we're trying to pass in Latitude/Longitude co-ords to the query, where they should be used to pull out users in a certain radius of the given point.

The query works fine when entered manually, but when dumping the SQL after calling the scope, it has escaped the . within the float.

Code:

```
public static function scopeInRadius($query, $lat, $lng, $distance = 50)
{
        $qstring = '
        ( 3959 * acos(
            cos( radians( '.$lat.') )
          * cos( radians( latitude ) )
          * cos( radians( longitude) - radians('.$lng.') )
          + sin( radians( '.$lat.') )
          * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                     )
        )';
    return $query->where($qstring, '<', $distance);
}
```

On `var_dump()'ing` `->toSql()`, I'm presented with the following output:

```
string 'select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `
        ( 3959 * acos(
            cos( radians( 53`.`258100) )
          * cos( radians( latitude ) )
          * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(2`.`127400) )
          + sin( radians( 53`.`258100) )
          * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                     )
        )` < ?' (length=376)``
```

I'm sure that there must be a fairly simply method to escape these periods, though as yet I've been unable to find it! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **whereRaw** instead of **where**, just make sure you cast the parameters to float for security reasons:

```
$lng = floatval($lng);
$lat = floatval($lat);
$distance = floatval($distance);

return $query->whereRaw($qstring . ' < ' . $distance);
```

Comment: Spot on, did the trick. Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `whereRaw()` method. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The value of your qstring variable should be

```
$qstring = "
    ( 3959 * acos(
        cos( radians( ".$lat.") )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(".$lng.") )
      + sin( radians( ".$lat.") )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                 )
    )";
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this results in a very similar output:



    `string 'select * from \`users\` where \`users\`.\`deleted_at\` is null and \`
        ( 3959 * acos(
            cos( radians( '53\`.\`258100') )
          * cos( radians( latitude ) )
          * cos( radians( longitude) - radians('2\`.\`127400') )
          + sin( radians( '53\`.\`258100') )
          * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                     )
        )\` < ?' (length=350)`

I'm weighing up forcing it in as a string and then casting it back, a bit hacky though...

--Edit: I can't get this to format as code!

Comment: Still the same output, unfortunately. running the `$qstring` section directly against MySQL gives the correct, expected result - It's just once it's forced into Eloquent's `->where()` where it seems it's being str_replace'd as it believes they're column delimiters.